# What would be the expected product of two samples from same distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, expected-value

What would be the $\mathbb{E}[x_ix_j]$ while $x_i,x_j \sim X$

where $x_i$ and $x_j$ 
 are independent and X have finite moments.

Comment: Assuming $i\not = j$ and independent samples, $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j] = (E[X])^2$. If $i = j$ then  $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j] = E[X^2]=\text{Var}(X)+ (E[X])^2$.

Comment: Are $x_i$ and $x_j$ independent?  Does the distribution $X$ have finite moments?  You need to add more information.

Comment: Yes, for both condition. Then is it okay to think that the answer is $(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$ as @Henry said?

Comment: Thanks, @drhab. I edited the question as you recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the sampled distribution has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and distinct samples are uncorrelated. In terms of the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), $$\Bbb E[x_ix_j]=\Bbb E[x_i]\Bbb E[x_j]+\operatorname{Cov}[x_i,\,x_j]=\mu^2+\sigma^2\delta_{ij}.$$